# Windows Media Player Object with Video_TS Files - No Sound Anymore

Tags: audio, windows-media-player

I copied a bunch of my DVDs (yes, owned) to a drive and created a basic webpage to be able to search and play them. I am using the code at the bottom to create a Windows Media Player object and then play the video. The video files are pulled off the DVD in the original format so each movie has files like this:

- VTS_01_0.BUP
- VTS_01_0.IFO
- VTS_01_1.VOB
- VTS_01_2.VOB
- VTS_01_3.VOB
- VTS_01_4.VOB
- VTS_01_5.VOB
- VTS_01_6.VOB

This all worked great until just recently. On my dev machine, I can play the videos but now, all of a sudden, there is no sound. I have tried the following but no luck:

- The video is not muted and the sound is at 50%
- Under the sound icon, under mixer, I checked IE and it is fine
- Sound works fine using another program, says WinAmp
- Opening Windows Media Player directly from the Start Menu and then playing the same movie works fine and I get sound
- I ensured that the option in IE to play sound on websites is checked
- I can play sound on other people's websites where they have embedded WMP files
- I tried resetting all of the IE settings on the Advanced tab in IE
- I tried my website, with my code below on another computer, AND IT WORKS FINE!
- I tried copying the media files listed above from the computer that works fine to my dev computer and it still doesn't work.
- If I try using a ".wmv" file, the sound does work

By the way, I am using Win7 with IE8. As you can see, this is driving me crazy! Why would it stop working on my one computer and the same code and files work fine on another computer? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<OBJECT id="mediaPlayer" width="640px" height="480px" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;"  CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" type="application/x-oleobject">   
<PARAM NAME="URL" VALUE="E:\test\VIDEO_TS\VIDEO_TS.IFO" />
<PARAM NAME="SendPlayStateChangeEvents" VALUE="True"/>
<PARAM NAME="AutoStart" VALUE="True"/>
<PARAM NAME="uiMode" VALUE="full"/>
<PARAM NAME="volume" VALUE="50" />
<PARAM NAME="PlayCount" VALUE="9999"/>
<PARAM NAME="fullScreen" VALUE="true"/>
<PARAM NAME="enableContextMenu" VALUE="true"/>
</OBJECT>
```